MobilePushSDK Hangs
After updating the library from cocoapods to SPM (and from version 7.6 to 8.1.2) we observed our hang rate increasing from 9.2 seconds/hour to 74.5 seconds/hour.
Apparently these hangs are occuring on Data Migration store access methods (related with Core Data).
Any idea on how to fix it ?




Thank you for this. It would greatly assist us if you could share the hang stack trace along with screenshots from the Xcode organizer for us to troubleshoot it better. Also, please provide the above requested information by creating an investigation with us.
Thanks, Prakashini

Here it is. Please let me know with you need anything else @PrakashiniPattabiraman

Thank you @fegoulart for providing the information.
